# Assert that values from array are checked in drop down

Tags: javascript, arrays, automation, protractor, automated-tests

I can't find the best solution to check that the elements (values - string) from array are checked in dropdown menu.
Here is part of my html (drop down)

```
<div _ngcontent-c5="" class="dropdown-item">
    <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="dropdown-item">
                    <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                      <input _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" id="dog1">
                      <label _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-label" for="dog1">Dog</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="dropdown-item">
                    <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                      <input _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" id="cat2">
                      <label _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-label" for="cat2">Cat</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="dropdown-item">
                    <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                      <input _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" id="horse3">
                      <label _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-label" for="horse3">Horse</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

on inputs, I can check that element `isSelected`.
I want to take values (checked) from labels to and check it contains in my array, but I have problem to write function that will create array with labels which are selected.

I've try sth like this (just only for test that I do it right i used console log instead od push to array). But it doesn't work.

```
var categories = $$('.custom-checkbox');

this.assertTest = function () {
        categories.filter(function (element, index) {
            if (element.isSelected()) {
                element.$('label').get(index).getText().then(function (ele) {
                    console.log(ele);
                })
            }
        })
        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use combination of [Pseudo Class](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_checked.asp) and [Adjacent Sibling](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) of CSS Selector.

```
let selectedOptsText = element.all(by.css('.dropdown-item input:checked + label'))
                      .getText();

// how to use selectedOptsText
selectedOptsText.then(function(txts){
   console.log(txts) // txts has those checked text
});
```

Approach of using `filter` and `map`:

```
let selectedOptsText = // it's a promise

// Find all check boxes
element.all(by.css('.dropdown-item input[type="checkbox"]'))

// Filter to keep ones are checked
.filter(function(checkbox){
    return checkbox.isSelected();
})
// After filter, checkboxes passed down to map() are all checked
.map(function(checkbox){
    // first get checkbox's parent, then get the label of same parent
    return checkbox.element(by.xpath('./../label'))
        .getText();
});

// how to use selectedOptsText
selectedOptsText.then(function(txts){
   console.log(txts) // txts has those checked text
});
```

Approach of using `each`:

```
let selectedOptsText = []; // to store checked text
let promiseA = 

// Find all check boxes
element.all(by.css('.dropdown-item input[type="checkbox"]'))

// Iterate each checkbox, store its text into selectedOptsText, if it's checked
.each(function(checkbox){
    checkbox.isSelected().then(function(selected){
        if(selected) {
            checkbox.element(by.xpath('./../label'))
            .getText()
            .then(function(txt){
                selectedOptsText.push(txt);
            });
        }
    })
});

// how to use selectedOptsText, it's different with above approach
promiseA.then(function() {
    console.log(selectedOptsText); // selectedOptsText has those checked text
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it on tuesday. It looks so easy, i lost whole day to find solution...:) But, can You give me example how can I do it with, filter or map function? Becouse i think I'm not understend them. I would be grateful to you

Comment: Thanks a lot for examples.with desctiptions!!:)